# How to parse multiple BB Code quote blocks, separately?

Tags: regex, laravel

I have created functionality where users can quote multiple users.

The problem is, the pattern matching seems to match the beginning [quote=] and the end [/quote], but they are from two separate instances of a quote.

The regex from the library is as follows:

```
    'quote' => [
        'pattern' => '/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/s',
        'replace' => '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>',
        'content' => '$1',
    ],
```

The output looks a little something like this:

```
Torrey Langworth said:
Doloribus reprehenderit incidunt sed odit. Voluptate et exercitationem fugiat quae a. Tempora voluptate repellendus similique quisquam. Reprehenderit qui qui consequatur eos et tempora dolorum.
[/quote]
hey


[quote=Shanelle Lubowitz II] said:
Et laudantium soluta eveniet molestias et est. Omnis at dolore qui dolorem quo doloremque. Nemo dolor est voluptatibus eos.


you
```

Notice that the first [/quote] is not captured to close off the initial quote, which would allow text to be entered in between.

Can anyone please offer me any help or possible solution? :) Would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to do this, I ended up with the code below - I just didn't know what the function did I guess, but I eventually ended up with the code below:

```
    'quote' => [
        'pattern' => '/\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/s',
        'replace' => '<blockquote>$1, $2</blockquote>',
        'content' => '$1',
    ],
```

Note the $1 is the first part of the expression ((.*?)), $2 encompasses the second part ((.*?)). So together, you get the divided BB code :D, except it split into two separate lines!